# Number of combinations without given pairs

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

Given a set of elements {e1, e2, ... en}, a set of pairs of these elements (each element may be present in several pairs) and a number k.

I need to count how many combinations of size k exist which not include any pair?

For example: if there only one pair {e1, e2} result in number of all combinations without elements e1 and e2. It may be counted in constant time: $$C^k_n - C^{k-2}_{n-2}$$

This task can be solved with the naive algorithm on python:

```
def combinations_without_pairs(elements, pairs, k):
    def iterable_len(iterable):
        return sum(1 for _ in iterable)

    def not_include_pairs(combination):
        for pair in pairs:
            if pair[0] in combination and pair[1] in combination:
                return False
        return True

    return iterable_len(filter(not_include_pairs, itertools.combinations(elements, k)))
```

But this algorithm is ineffective: it requires iterating over each element combination and each pair.

Is there any way to solve this problem with better complexity? At least reduce the impact of a big count of elements and pairs?

I want to find an algorithm with the lowest time complexity.

Answer (score 7):

Don't expect an efficient algorithm.  This is the problem of counting the number of [independent sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) in an undirected graph.  This problem is [#P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete) [1,2], so there is unlikely to be any effective algorithm that works for arbitrary graphs.

See https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/10700/5038 for techniques you could use.

[1] [The complexity of counting cuts and of computing the probability that a graph is connected](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0212053), J. Scott Provan and Michael O. Ball, SIAM J. Computing, 12:4.

[2] [The complexity of counting in sparse, regular, and planar graphs](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0097539797321602), Salil P. Vadhan, SIAM J. Computing, 31:2(398--427).